# RegEx - find all occurrences of a word and exclude certain words that contain it

Tags: regex

searching all over couldn't find a solution and also am breaking my head with this for a while already.

I want to search for all occurrences (**words not sentences containing**) of word `end` but exclude certain words from being found - that I want to specify myself.

For example, I am interested in all possible combinations of (**should match**):

- end
- ended
- date-end
- hasEnded
- end_date

but I want to exclude all these words for example (**should not match**):

- render
- appendTo
- extend
- renderGrid

while not selecting the whole lines, only the matching words.

The closest I could get is this regex: [`(?!extend|appendTo|render|renderGrid)(\b.*end.*\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/cDvRW2/1) but this selects the whole lines **and more-over doesn't work in *Search in files* in IntelliJ IDEs which is frustrating**.

Anybody willing to improve and make it working in *Search in files* in IDEs?

Comment: You seem to want `(?<!\S)(?!(?:extend|appendTo|render|renderGrid)(?!\S))\S*end\S*`

Answer (score 1):

You could match 0+ times a non whitespace char `\S*` at both ends or use a character class `[\w-]*` and specify what you would allow to match.

You might omit the capturing group and get the matches only.

```
(?!extend|append|render|renderGrid)\b\S*end\S*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZkNXJ/1)